# xpath set context need for iteration

Tags: c++, xpath

I need to iterate the setContent. the argument is a xmlNodePtr

```
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[5]");
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[6]");
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[7]");
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[8]");
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[9]");
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[10]");
.
.
.
.
```

I tried using for loop like this that doesnt work.

```
for( int i=5 ;i=size+1;i++)
xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[i]")
```

can anyone please let me know how to achieve iteration of the setContent

Comment: Which class `xpath` belongs to? Which library/compiler are you using? What is `setContent()` supposed to do? (Calling it repeatedly with different parameters without doing anything else seems strange)

Answer (score 3):

How about using a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to construct the string:

```
for(int i = 5; i = size + 1; i++)
{
    std::istringstream iss;
    iss << "/*/*/*/*/*[" << i << ']';

    xpath.setContent(iss.str());
}
```

Or even better, use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) if it's available:

```
for(int i = 5; i = size + 1; i++)
{
    xpath.setContent("/*/*/*/*/*[" + std::to_string(i) + "]");
}
```

Comment: @PavithraChandramohan If you get it even when including `<string>` then your compiler is not fully up to date with the latest standard, and you have to use the code with the `stringstream`.

Comment: xpath.setContent(xmlNodePtr node); --> is the function im calling so i have to transform the string "/*/*/*/*/*[5]" to the node..  ANY IDEA??